# Ensuring security for SharePoint hosted app (Office 365)

Tags: source-code, code-review

What strategy/approach/method should I use to ensure that programmers aren't deliberately including backdoor or accidentally creating security flaws? This is in regards to SharePoint hosted app in Office 365, when deployment is through Visual Studio Team Services (Visual Studio Online) - continuous integration https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/continuous-integration/.

What automated tool would you recommend, that have an OWSAP benchmark? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools

Comment: tool recommendations are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend code review by peer developers. Introduce a policy where no code can be added unless it has been reviewed by someone else. The reviewer can be another developer, it doesn't have to be a senior or a dedicated reviewer.

This reduces the chance of errors. It makes it harder to put some hidden functionality in the code. And it works great for sharing knowledge within the developer team.